# Unable to run subprocess in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

I am trying to run command like 'sed', 'pwd' using subprocess module in PyCharm(installed on Windows 10). But it is giving me error as below. Though same codes are working fine in VS Code.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('pwd')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\name\something.py",
> line 14, in 
> subprocess.call('pwd')   File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 339, in call
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:   File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 800, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1207, in _execute_child
> startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

This is happening for any command I am trying to run through subprocess. And subprocess import is working fine, just the subprocess.call() is giving issues.

Please let me know if any leads on this. I tried several things, but not able to resolve the issue yet. Thanks.

Edit:
I am getting same error with any command I am passing to subprocess.call().

```
subprocess.call("echo hello world")
```

Comment: Can you post your sample code and describe what OS you're running on?

Comment: @Craab, edited with these details.

Comment: Try replacing `pwd` with `dir` since you are using Windows

Answer (score 0):

from the error I can see that you are using a windows machine, and when I test it windows don't have a past working directory command or the "pwd" command on cmd, try calling in `subprocess.call("echo hello world")` just to make sure everything is working

Comment: "pwd" is working fine when i am trying this on VS Code(On Windows machine). And this issue I am facing with any command for that matter. I even tried with subprocess.call('date'), it worked on VS Code but not working in PyCharm. "echo" is also erroring out with same errors.

Comment: well i tested and i find why, pwd or past working directory is actually available on powershell, vs code defaults to using powershell but pycharm uses the command prompt, reply back if there are any new problems

Comment: It makes sense for 'pwd'. But I am getting same error even with subprocess.call("echo hello world"), or for any command I am running through subprocess.

Comment: can you give me the errors? i never seen something like this happen before so yeah

Comment: Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\something.py", line 14, in <module>
    subprocess.call("echo hello")
  File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\name\Miniconda3\envs\local_test3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: hmm, can you show me your pycharm environment, are you using a different version of python, have you tried opening the pycharm project with vs code to see if it works there, those are the tips i can give to help you debug this problem

Comment: 1. Does `echo hello` run in terminal window?

Comment: 2. Did you try Python console for this bit of code?